# Virtualbox NAT guest suddenly has no internect access

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Ubuntu 17.10 host, Virtualbox 5.1.34_Ubuntu r121010.

In Virtualbox I have a couple guest systems – Windows 10, Linux Mint, Fedora – that had been working just fine, they had internet access.  They all were set up with the NAT attachment.

Yesterday, for some reason I cannot figure out, they all lost internet access.

When I experimented and change the attachment setting from NAT to Bridged, they all again had internet access.

How can I figure out what the problem is with the NAT attachment setting?

Comment: It might narrow down the possibilities if you could be more specific than "lost internet access" - failed DNS resolution? no route to host? something else?

Comment: When using NAT, if in any guest OS I attempt to navigate to any external web site using Firefox, Firefox says (trying google as an example):  "Hmm, We're having trouble finding that site.  We can't connect to the server at www.google.com.  If that address is correct, here are three other things you can try:  Try again later.  /  Check your network connection.  /  If you are connected but behind a firewall, check that Firefox has permission to access the Web."  

Changing NAT to Bridged enables Firefox in the guest OS to access the Web just fine.

Sorry..  What else may be useful for you?